# Git commands not in context menu for Document Library

Tags: git, windows-7, contextmenu

I'm using Git version `1.9.5.msysgit.1` and Win 7 Enterprise.

When I navigate to the folder `C:\Users\[userid]\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects` using a regular sequence of folder jumps starting from `C:`, then right-click in the folder window, I get all the usual Git context menu commands, e.g. Git Bash.

However, when I go to the same folder starting from the Document Library, either from the Start Menu or clicking in the Libraries on the left side of the folder window, the Git context menu commands are missing.

Do I need to change some Git settings for these commands to appear in the Document Library context menu?

Answer (score 3):

You probably have a key in your registry similar to this:

```lisp
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\bash\command]
@="cmd /c start /d \"%v\" bash"
```

You need to add a key similar to this:

```lisp
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\LibraryFolder\background\shell\bash\command]
@="cmd /c start /d \"%v\" bash"
```

Comment: Curiously, I don't have any `bash` keys in my registry (I searched for the string "bash" and found no results).

Comment: @sigil do I really need to spell this out for you? The important part is `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\LibraryFolder\background\shell\...`, not `bash`

Comment: I have this key: `[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\background\shell\cmd\command] @=cmd.exe /s /k pushd "%V"`  But in `[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\LibraryFolder\background]` I don't have a `shell` key, and none of the other keys in `LibraryFolder` have a `command` key nested.  Should I create the key `[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\LibraryFolder\background\shell\cmd\command]`?

Comment: @sigil sorry, but if you have this little idea about the Windows registry, then you shouldnt be messing with it